# Google API Php listFiles();

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I have a slight problem, and I'm not sure if i'm missing something here. I am building a website where the user logs in and authorizes google etc and keeps the refresh token in the db (which works fine)

I also get the userinfo (which also works fine).

But whenever I try to get the list of files the user has, the items return 0. I am using this code:

```
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
                $drive = new apiDriveService($client);
                $result = $drive->files->listFiles();
                $countArray = count($result['items']) - 1;
                foreach($result['items'] as $i=>$row){
                    $isFirst = ($i == 0);
                    $isLast = ($i == $countArray);

                    $sql = "INSERT INTO docs (title, notecontent, folderid, filestatus, linkhref, useremail) 
                            VALUES (".$row['title'].",".$row['id'].", 2, 1,".$row['alternateLink'].", ".$usernamei.")";
                    $db->query($sql, true);
                }
            }
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is get a list of files the user has and save them in a database.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Thanks !

Comment: Btw when i tried this aside with just an index.php and everything in the same file it worked..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing $client->accessType and $client->useObjects seemed to do the job ... :)